# Dynamic Website using AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I want to host a dynamic website using AWS serverless. I plan to use Lambda, API Gateway, DynamoDB and S3. My frontend pages will reside in S3. The blocker is that there would be some dynamic items such as Usernames and other metadata which will be user-specific. I know so far that the best we can do is pull the html page from S3. How do I then go ahead and include these variables in those pages?

I would be writing lambda in NodeJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your HTML (static page) should have all the input fields (in your case user name and meta data). You can use any clide side javascript library to take values from those input fields. Even you can use classic JavaScript (like document.getElementById ) to take values from input fields but that will be the pretty old way of doing even if it works.Once you take the needed values then you can compose Json out of that to call lambda function via API gateway. Though S3 supports only static web site hosting you can write JavaScript code inside your HTML, which will not consider as dynamic (like C#, Java etc. ).

Big story short you can acheive anything through JavaScript in the static page you hosted in S3 and compose proper Json in the way your Api gateway / Lambda expecting.

Answer (score 0):

What you mentioned as blocker for **dynamic items such as usernames and other metadata**. You can use AngularJS or other Framework to handle dynamic variable in application.

You can also use AWS Cognito for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

For a serverless website like you describe you need to make the distinction between the static, and the dynamic content.

The static content, like HTML pages, Javascript files, CSS can be hosted in an S3 bucket.

For dynamic items you can use Javascript or any JS framework, and use it to interact with a couple of lambda's that return dynamic data.
These lambdas can be attached to an API gateway.

If you want to store- and retrieve data to a database you can use DynamoDB, or an RDS instance, that way you don't need to manage any servers

If it is just about authentication you can use AWS Cognito.

Answer (score -1):

AWS S3 is fine for the front with angular for exemple.

For api I use nodejs in docker container in Aws ECS.

Comment: A dynamic website relies on multiple urls. Angular is used for single page applications